# @ngrx/effects : Organizing effects in separate Angular libraries properly

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, monorepo

We are using several consumer-facing Angular SPAs that contain features which are identical but also different [as you would expect]. The root store reducer for each SPA are similar but slightly different to support each SPA's use cases.

For example, we have an authentication feature that everyone uses. It relies on AuthenticationEffects to do server-side validation. This effect also relies on the store to check to see if the user is already authenticated using the pipe withLatestFrom. There it will grab some data from the store to see if an authentication token is already present.

...and here's where I am stuck. I want to make AuthenticationEffects available from an Angular library so it can be re-used across all SPAs. However, that library doesn't have access to the store because the root store reducers are each located in their respective SPAs.

Now some effects are very specific and deserve to live in their respective SPA, but many can be modularized for re-use.

So far, I am able to re-use actions and reducers by adding them to domain-specific Angular libraries. However, I can't figure out how to get the effects out of the SPAs.

Currently, we have to duplicate these effects in each SPA.

FYI As far as architecture decisions go, after quite a bit of reading, we have chosen to go with one store per SPA. We do not use StoreModule.forFeature or EffectsModule.forFeature in any of our lazy loaded modules because of timing concerns. The store is fully initialized and ready to go in AppModule.

Thoughts and feedback appreciated

Comment: Did you find a solution? I got the same issue. The only solution I get so far is to copy all the effect code into the app which can cause further issue down the line if any code is changed on one of the effect.